# Problema al pivotear un dataframe a partir de dos dataframes concatenados

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pivot

Uso Python 3.5 y Pandas 0.20.3

Obtengo un error cuando intento pivotar un dataframe de pandas el cual he obtenido mediante la función concat.

Detallo el proceso.

Este es mi primer dataframe.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
['2017-01-03 21:00:00','2017-01-03 21:00:00','2017-01-04 21:00:00','2017-01-04 21:00:00',
 '2017-01-05 21:00:00','2017-01-05 21:00:00'],
['RUT','RUT','RUT','RUT','RUT','RUT'],[65.00,26.00,-47.00,-8.00,32.00,10.00],
[59.09,20.21,-53.12,-13.96,26.45,4.25]]).T   df.columns=[['Fecha_Hora','Ticker_Suby','Rtdo_Bruto_x_Estrat','Rtdo_Neto_x_Estrat']] df = df.sort_values(by=['Ticker_Suby','Fecha_Hora',], ascending=True)
```

Asi, que obtengo:

> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Después agrupo y sumo las filas por `TickerSuby` y `FechaHora`.

```
a = df.groupby(by=['Ticker_Suby','Fecha_Hora',]).sum() a.head(100)
```

> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces uso la función `concat` para unir el dataframe `'a'` con el dataframe `'df'` y calculo las sumas acumuladas de las columnas `'Rtdo_Bruto_x_Estrat'` y `'Rtdo_Neto_x_Estrat'`.

```
df = pd.concat([a.groupby(level=[1]).cumsum(),a.groupby(level=[0]).cumsum().add_suffix('_cum')], 1) df.reset_index(drop=False)
```

> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Bien, mi problema es que intento pivotar este dataframe `df` utilizando la columna '`Fecha_Hora'` como índice pero obtengo el siguiente error:

> ```
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
> KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
> C:\Users\Angel\Anaconda44\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
>    2392         uniques : index
> -> 2393         """
>    2394         if self.is_unique and not dropna:
>
> pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\_libs\index.c:5239)()
>
> pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\_libs\index.c:5085)()
>
> pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas\_libs\hashtable.c:20405)()
>
> pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas\_libs\hashtable.c:20359)()
>
> KeyError: 'Fecha_Hora'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
>  in ()
> ----> 1 df1 = a.pivot(index="Fecha_Hora",columns ="Ticker_Suby",values = "Rtdo_Bruto_x_Estrat")
>       2 df1.head()
>       3 
>
> C:\Users\Angel\Anaconda44\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in pivot(self, index, columns, values)
>    3949         Returns
>    3950         -------
> -> 3951         unstacked : DataFrame or Series
>    3952         """
>    3953         from pandas.core.reshape.reshape import unstack
>
> C:\Users\Angel\Anaconda44\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\reshape.py in pivot(self, index, columns, values)
>     373             index = self.index
>     374         else:
> --> 375             index = self[index]
>     376         indexed = Series(self[values].values,
>     377                          index=MultiIndex.from_arrays([index, self[columns]]))
>
> C:\Users\Angel\Anaconda44\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
>    2060         -------
>    2061         q : DataFrame
> -> 2062 
>    2063         Notes
>    2064         -----
>
> C:\Users\Angel\Anaconda44\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in _getitem_column(self, key)
>    2067         multidimensional key (e.g., a DataFrame) then the result will be passed
>    2068         to :meth:`DataFrame.__getitem__`.
> -> 2069 
>    2070         This method uses the top-level :func:`pandas.eval` function to
>    2071         evaluate the passed query.
>
> C:\Users\Angel\Anaconda44\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in _get_item_cache(self, item)
>    1532 
>    1533         multicolumn : boolean, default True
> -> 1534             Use \multicolumn to enhance MultiIndex columns.
>    1535             The default will be read from the config module.
>    1536 
>
> C:\Users\Angel\Anaconda44\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py in get(self, item, fastpath)
>    3588 
>    3589             if not isnull(item):
> -> 3590                 loc = self.items.get_loc(item)
>    3591             else:
>    3592                 indexer = np.arange(len(self.items))[isnull(self.items)]
>
> C:\Users\Angel\Anaconda44\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
>    2393         """
>    2394         if self.is_unique and not dropna:
> -> 2395             return self
>    2396 
>    2397         values = self.values
>
> pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\_libs\index.c:5239)()
>
> pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\_libs\index.c:5085)()
>
> pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas\_libs\hashtable.c:20405)()
>
> pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas\_libs\hashtable.c:20359)()
>
> KeyError: 'Fecha_Hora'
>
> ----------------------
> ```

También he intentado aplicar algo más simple como:

```
a.pivot_table(df,index=["Fecha_Hora",'Rtdo_Bruto_x_Estrat_cum'])
```

Pero obtengo:

> ```
> KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
>  in ()
>       1 #df1 = a.pivot(index="Fecha_Hora",columns ="Ticker_Suby",values = "Rtdo_Bruto_x_Estrat")
>       2 #df1.head()
> ----> 3 a.pivot_table(df,index=["Fecha_Hora",'Rtdo_Bruto_x_Estrat_cum'])
>
> C:\Users\Angel\Anaconda44\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\pivot.py in pivot_table(data, values, index, columns, aggfunc, fill_value, margins, dropna, margins_name)
>     110         for i in values:
>     111             if i not in data:
> --> 112                 raise KeyError(i)
>     113 
>     114         to_filter = []
>
> KeyError: 'Rtdo_Bruto_x_Estrat_cum'
>
> ------------------------------
> ```

He buscado en la red qué puede estar equivocado pero no he encontrado nada.

Algo que sí he notado pueder estar relacionado es el dataframe df que obtengo al aplicar concat ejecutado en el IDE Pycharm. Como veis en la imagen el campo fechahora aparece como "desactivado" o "no operativo".

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Perdón, pensé que estaba en la versión en inglés. Ya está traducido a español. Gracias

Comment: Hola @AngelGálvez , no se si termino de entender cual es la salida que esperas, en todo caso tu último intento debería ser algo así: `df = pd.pivot_table(df,  index=["Fecha_Hora",'Rtdo_Bruto_x_Estrat_cum'])` No puedes aplicar `pivot` sobre `a` porque a no tiene la columna 'Rtdo_Bruto_x_Estrat_cum', esta pertenece a `df` resultado de `concat`. ¿Cómo debería ser la salida esperada para tu ejemplo? ¿Simplemente tratas de crear un multiindex con las columnas "Fecha_Hora"  y 'Rtdo_Bruto_x_Estrat_cum' como indices?

Comment: Hola FjSevilla, necesito aplicar un pivot al dataframe producto de la concatenación para poder graficar el dataframe resultado con la libreria plot.ly. He añadido una imagen de lo que obtengo haciendo este concat en pycharm donde se puede apreciar que por algun motivo la columna FechaHora queda como desactiva o no operativa. Tiene pintas de que eso puede estar relacionado con el hecho de que incluso usando df1 = df.pivot(index="Fecha_Hora",columns ="Ticker_Suby")
df1.head() obtengo el mismo error mostrado mas arriba.

Comment: Como dato esto es lo que utilizo para preparar el df al graficarlo.df1 = settings.df_Rtdo_Estrategia_Cerrada_xSuybDiayHora.pivot(index="Fecha_Hora",columns ="Ticker_Suby",values = "Rtdo_Neto_Acum_x_Estrat")
df1 = df1.fillna(method = "ffill")
df1.iplot(kind = "line", margin =(40,25,50,25)).. Funcionaba perfectamente hasta que utilizo un df que proviene de una funcion concat. Para el ejemplo que he puesto he utilizado un ejemplo mas simple cambiando el nombre de los dataframes pero persiguiendo hacer el mismo pivot.

Comment: Te comento: necesito utilizar los dos campos que tengos agrupados "Fecha_Hora" y "Ticker_Suby" por separados. El primero será el index y el segundo columns dentro del pivot_table. Aquí te pongo la sentencia: df2 =df = pd.pivot_table(df, index=["Fecha_Hora"],columns ="Ticker_Suby",values = "Rtdo_Neto_x_Estrat_cum").  Pero me sale el error  grouped = data.groupby(keys)  Ticker_Suby ya que parece que no reconoce este campo como un campo normal y creo yo que es debido a que esta agrupados con Ticker_Suby.  Por eso te he puesto la imagen última para que vieras que no reconoce como campos las claves

Comment: En cuanto a tu penúltimo comentario ten en cuenta que en tu código no reseteas el indice  y sto es lo que causa que la columna no se encuentre, debes hacer `df.reset_index(drop=False,  inplace= True)`.